# Pressflow Install - Redirect to database configuration without error

Tags: redirection, installation, 6

I am currently installing the database in the conguration distribution "Pressflow." I have already installed apc and varnish.

During installation, I put the access to the database and when I click OK, I am automatically redirected to the same page. This does not create the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that in your `settings.php` all your configurations are properly set. (e.g `$db_url`, `$base_url` ..)

Comment: I have manually add this line : $db_url = ‘mysql://username:password@localhost/databasename’;

Comment: Glad you solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need create the database manually first.

Comment: The database is already created  and there are no error message

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: Pressflow version 6.26

Comment: I am testing the same version and when I access to http://localhost/pressflow/install.php and click 'Install Pressflow in English', then I automatically have installed all tables.